# Showing nested polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector

I am working with QGIS and in particular with river basins.

If you see my picture below, each label shows a particular basin but actually only the biggest is shown (because I think its area covers the areas of the smaller ones).

[image]

e.g. 4103600 is the largest basin and its boundaries are shown correctly, but within it there are 7 more nested basins (i.e. 4103631, 4103650, 4103615, 4103610, 4103750, 4103751 and 4103570).

**How can I show ALL the basins' boundaries (i.e. nested and non-nested) with QGIS?**

I believe there should be a trick for doing so but I don't know which one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to view the other polygons then the easiest method would be to set the 'Feature blending mode' to 'Multiply', found under the layer properties style tab.[image: polygons with multiply feature blending]

Alternatively change the fill style transparency or remove the fill altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems that the function `Style -> Inverted Polygons` works for my purpose.

[image]

thanks